# If condition and Date Conversion in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML with me !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Rowsets CachedTime="" DateCreated="2013-07-30T00:13:32" EndDate="2013-07-30T00:13:29" StartDate="2013-07-29T23:13:29" Version="12.2.4 Build(92)">
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="Name" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Name" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Name"/>
            <Column Description="Value" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Value" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Value"/>
            <Column Description="Datatype" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Datatype" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Datatype"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <Name>NameOfEquipment</Name>
            <Value>OLOA-A</Value>
            <Datatype>String</Datatype>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Name>UnloadDate</Name>
            <Value>2014-01-25T11:00:05</Value>
            <Datatype>String</Datatype>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="Name" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Name" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Name"/>
            <Column Description="Value" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Value" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Value"/>
            <Column Description="Datatype" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Datatype" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Datatype"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <Name>NameOfEquipment</Name>
            <Value>OLOA-B</Value>
            <Datatype>String</Datatype>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Name>UnloadDate</Name>
            <Value>2014-01-22T13:00:05</Value>
            <Datatype>String</Datatype>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="Name" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Name" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Name"/>
            <Column Description="Value" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Value" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Value"/>
            <Column Description="Datatype" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Datatype" SQLDataType="-9" SourceColumn="Datatype"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <Name>NameOfEquipment</Name>
            <Value>OLOA-C</Value>
            <Datatype>String</Datatype>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Name>UnloadDate</Name>
            <Value>2014-01-19T08:10:05</Value>
            <Datatype>String</Datatype>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Now, i am using following XSLT to convert it to different format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <Rowset>
                <Columns>
                    <xsl:apply-templates mode="cols" select="Rowset[1]/Row"/>
                </Columns>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Rowset"/>
            </Rowset>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Row" mode="cols">
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="{Name}" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="{Name}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Rowset">
        <Row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Row/Name"/>
        </Row>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Name">
        <xsl:element name="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="../Value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get proper output as  following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Rowsets CachedTime="" DateCreated="2013-07-30T00:13:32" EndDate="2013-07-30T00:13:29" StartDate="2013-07-29T23:13:29" Version="12.2.4 Build(92)">
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="NameOfEquipment" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="NameOfEquipment"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="UnloadDate" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="UnloadDate"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <NameOfEquipment>OLOA-A</NameOfEquipment>
            <UnloadDate>2014-01-25T11:00:05</UnloadDate>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <NameOfEquipment>OLOA-B</NameOfEquipment>
            <UnloadDate>2014-01-22T13:00:05</UnloadDate>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <NameOfEquipment>OLOA-C</NameOfEquipment>
            <UnloadDate>2014-01-19T08:10:05</UnloadDate>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Now my requirement is, I need to convert `<UnloadDate>` into "DD/MM/YYYY:HH:MM:SS" format if I get Plant as India else I need to convert it to "MM/DD/YYYY:HH:MM:SS".

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where is "Plant as India"?

Comment: This is a display requirement. Change the date "on the fly" in the portion of the application that *displays* the data. Don't change it in the base data, that's not wise.

Comment: I will take 'Plant' as param and will pass it from the application dynamically.

Comment: If you're talking about XSLT and date handling in the same breath then you absolutely need to tell us whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Tomalak that you should think twice about this. I am also puzzled by `:` separating between date and time. However, if you are sure, you can add these two templates to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="Name[.='UnloadDate']">
    <UnloadDate>
    <xsl:call-template name="convertDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="iDate" select="../Value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </UnloadDate>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="convertDate">
    <xsl:param name="iDate"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'/'"/>
    <xsl:param name="yyyy" select="substring($iDate, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:param name="mm" select="substring($iDate, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:param name="dd" select="substring($iDate, 9, 2)"/>
    <xsl:param name="t" select="substring($iDate, 12, 8)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Plant='India'">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($dd, $separator, $mm, $separator, $yyyy, ':', $t)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($mm, $separator, $dd, $separator, $yyyy, ':', $t)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This one works just perfectly. Yup, there was a typo. I wanted to separate Date and Time with SPACE and not ":" but I was at least able to do that :) Thanks a lot for your help !!